# getting middleware error as response in SFC Payment Gateway -> SFC Pay - Request Encryption API

Tags: php, ajax, api, ssg

I am getting middleware error as response on calling /skillsFutureCredits/claims/encryptRequests API

> API Url: https://uat-api.ssg-wsg.sg/skillsFutureCredits/claims/encryptRequests
> find SFC Pay - Request Encryption API [here](https://developer.ssg-wsg.gov.sg/webapp/docs/product/7KU1xrpxljJZnsIkJP6QNF/group/2RTLOUTuE3Dkgf7MOdn0Cm#/Encryption/post_skillsFutureCredits_claims_encryptRequests)

**Request body:**

```
{
   "claimRequest":{
      "course":{
         "id":"TGS-2020001822",
         "fee":"540",
         "runId":"229537",
         "startDate":"2021-09-06"
      },
      "individual":{
         "nric":"T5001072J",
         "email":"test+student@yopmail.com",
         "homeNumber":"9523456711",
         "mobileNumber":"9876543434"
      },
      "additionalInformation":"This is additional information"
   }
}
```

**Response from API:**

```
{
   "data":"Middleware error"
}
```

Please Answer if you found anything about it.

Comment: Perhaps something to do with the note on top of that second page you linked to? _"APIs will be unavailable due to scheduled maintenance from 3 Sep 2021 11:00 PM to 4 Sep 2021 06:00 AM."_

Comment: Its still gives the same response from API after maintenance